# How can I call lightning component from VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component,lightning controller and a custom 'New' button.Since custom button can only refer to VF page and not to lightning component.How can I make VF page to call lightning component as soon as custom 'New' button is clicked.

I cannot go with Quick Actions since I need this in List view and Actions cannot be added in List view.

Please help with this.

Comment: You can use `$Lightning.use` to include it in VF, for which pre-requisite is that you will need to create a lightning dependency app.  To call it on button click, it can be wrapped inside a javascript function which is called on button click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Lightning out](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html) to expose the Component to Visualforce.

Refer: [Use Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm). Information is online hence, not quoting from it. Let us know if you are stuck.

For navigation in lightning  on Visualforce, you would have to use [sforce.one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) object.

Comment: Raul, is there any alternative of lightning out or aura dependency? I need to provide a dynamic resource (With dynamic namespace) in aura dependency. I think we can't do that. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @Aakriti.G That's a good question but unrelated to this one, can you maybe post a new question with more details.